# how to avoid spikes when loading webView

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiwebview

As you know iOS apps crashs when they get many memory warnings on little time .. so to avoid this you should avoid spikes. One of acts that provokes spikes is loading `UIWebView`.

So my question: Is there a solution to avoid spikes when loading `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there is a solution to avoid spikes when loading UIWebView?

Not really, no. If you're seeing a spike when alloc/init-ing a `UIWebView`, then there's not a lot you can do. If it needs that much memory then it needs that much memory. It should never be so much that it causes problems though as the internals of `UIWebView` should be doing the right thing. If it's not and you're seeing a reproducible low memory crash when you shouldn't be expecting one, then file a radar about it. Obviously if you're loading a ginormous image into the web view then you would not expect it to work fine on old device with small amounts of RAM!

Comment: So,i think that the only way is one of two things:
-make webviews in a way that don't make memory spikes
-implement "didrecieveMemoryWarning" method t release unused memory if there is.

Comment: Indeed. You should definitely be implementing `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in all your view controllers. And `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Do you have examples i how implmenting  didReceiveMemoryWarning method?
Because , theorically is clear ,yes.. but in practise i did'nt do it ever.

Comment: You just need to release anything that you can create again later. Like maybe some state that you have stored.